# Is it possible to combine data from JSON object AND from columns? [C3JS]

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to combine 2 types of charts ('scatter' and 'line') having both different data's origin.

I'm able to display successfully each of them alone (hence the following screenshots), but not both together.

[image: Scatter] [image: Line Graphs]

My guess is that the use of data.keys override the display of the data coming from my columns, but I haven't found yet anything relevant to this problem.

```
var jsondata = [{
  "intentId": "QP3035",
  "intentName": "lapin",
  "confidence": 90,
  "occurences": 150
}, {
  "intentId": "QP4019",
  "intentName": "ours",
  "confidence": 80,
  "occurences": 140
}, {
  "intentId": "QP4022",
  "intentName": "chouette",
  "confidence": 60,
  "occurences": 60
}, {
  "intentId": "QP3032 ",
  "intentName": "cheval",
  "confidence": 21,
  "occurences": 120
}, {
  "intentId": "QP4029",
  "intentName": "poule",
  "confidence": 18,
  "occurences": 17
}];

jsondata = jsonfile.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.confidence - b.confidence;
});


var test = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#intentsConfidenceChart',
  data: {
    json: jsondata,
    keys: {
        x: 'confidence',
      value: ['confidence', 'occurences']
    },
    xs: {
        graphTop: 'x1',
        graphBot: 'x2'
    },
    columns: [
        ['x1',20,100],
        ['x2', 20,20,90,100,100],
        ['graphTop',160,160],
        ['graphBot',160,140,40,40,160]
    ],
    types:{
        occurences: 'scatter',
        graphTop:'line',
      graphBot:'line'
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      label: 'Confidence Level',
      tick: {
        fit: false
      }
    },
    y: {
      label: 'Occurences'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    contents: function(d) {
      return jsonfile[d[0].index].intentId + ' : ' + jsonfile[d[0].index].intentName;
    }
  }
});
```

(By the way, the reason I draw these graphs is that I would like to have a responsive region discriminating a certain area of my graph. I've struggled a lot with svg before starting to envisage this little hack.)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to mix jsondata with columns **directly**.

But you can **transform your json into array** and use it alongside with other arrays:

```
  data: {
    //json: jsondata,
    // keys: {
    //     x: 'confidence',
    //   value: ['confidence', 'occurences']
    // },
    xs: {
        graphTop: 'x1',
        graphBot: 'x2',
        confidence: 'occurences'
    },
    columns: [
        ['x1',20,100],
        ['x2', 20,20,90,100,100],
        ['graphTop',160,160],
        ['graphBot',160,140,40,40,160],
        ["confidence", 90, 80, 60, 21, 18],
        ["occurences", 150, 140 , 60, 120, 17]
    ],
```

Comment: Actually I can't because the Json data is expected to be loaded dynamically soon. So I need to get rid of rigid columns. I think I will try to draw on the svg the region.

Comment: What about transforming json data to arrays on-the-go and then putting it into chart with load method? http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load

Comment: I'll mark my question solved, even though it's not really what I was looking for in the beginning.